# Swift 3 JSON Multi-dimensional NSArray to String

Tags: swift

I am taking in a multi-dimensional array from JSON and trying to store it into a NSArray object.  I then want to iterate that object through picker.  This worked on Swift 2, but once I converted to swift 3 I get 'Type Any has no subscript members' errors in my pickerView function.

Relevant Code (names and faces changed):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let ticket_number =  pvds_ticket_number[row]["ticket_number"] as! String
    let customer_name = pvds_ticket_number[row]["customer_name"] as! String
    return "\(ticket_number) - \(customer_name)"
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    let ticket_number = pvds_ticket_number[row]["ticket_number"] as! String
    txt_ticket_number.text = ticket_number
}

func get_tickets ()
{
    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")
    let url_path: NSString = "my_url_that_isnt_relevant" as NSString;
    let url_path_formatted: NSString = url_path.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString

    let url = URL(string: url_path_formatted as String)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }


        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                if let results: NSArray = parseJSON["results"] as? NSArray{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.pvds_ticket_number = results as! [Any] as NSArray
                        self.pv_ticket_number.reloadAllComponents()
                    })
                }
        }

        } catch {
            print("something went wrong")
        }

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

These lines show the errors:
        let ticket_number =  pvds_ticket_number[row]["ticket_number"] as! String
        let customer_name = pvds_ticket_number[row]["customer_name"] as! String

Comment: Have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DType+Any+has+no+subscript+members

Comment: None of [these 53 results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswift3%5d%20Any%20has%20no%20subscript%20members) for a search with "Any has no subscript members" were helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`pvds_ticket_number` looks to be specified as `NSArray<Any>`. When you access it you are treating it like `NSArray<[String: String]>`.

The first line that is giving you issues is: `let ticket_number =  pvds_ticket_number[row]["ticket_number"] as! String`. The compiler knows that `pvds_ticket_number` is an array so using `[row]` works just fine. However the compiler has no idea what kind or object is at index `row` so it considers it to be type `Any`. As the compiler has rightly told you the type `Any` does not have a subscript method.

The easiest way to deal with this is to give the compiler more info about your `pvds_ticket_number` array. Currently when you assign it you use:

`self.pvds_ticket_number = results as! [Any] as NSArray`

To start with unless you specifically need something from `NSArray` that `Array` does not have consider using `Array`. In which case the above line would become something more like:

`self.pvds_ticket_number = results as! [[String: String]]`

This assumes that your array is an array of dictionaries with strings for the keys and the values both, you may need to alter that bit based on what the dictionaries are actually made of.

Comment: I corrected my code to use [String: String].  However I am now getting 'Ambiguous reference to remember subscript' on those lines that I got the previous error.

Comment: Somewhere you declare `pvds_ticket_number` as a variable. I'm guessing it is defined as `NSArray` there rather than `[String: String]`. If in doubt break up the line into multiple lines to get a better idea of where the issue actually is.

Comment: It is declared as var pvds_ticket_number = [String: String]()

Comment: Just saw I had a mistake in the last line of code. It should be `[[String: String]]`, not `[String: String]`. The first is an array of dictionaries, the second is a single dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I would use the swiftyjson cocoa pod. I used to struggle with similar issues, and it seemed like no matter how much I learned, they would always come up. Swiftyjson is light and easy to use so you don't have to accrue technical debt by sitting for hours trying to figure out a dumb simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

For someone like me who only dabbles in it because I am trying to make a simple app for work it is difficult.